# Does every closed subgroup of an abelian variety have a direct complement?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, abelian-varieties

Consider A is an Abelian variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and B is a closed subgroup of A. I think there is an Abelian variety $C$ such that $A$ and $B\oplus C$ are isogenic. But I can't find a reference for this fact or if it's false a counter example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $B$ is a closed subgroup of $A$? Do you mean (closed) subvariety?

Comment: no i mean a closed sub variety B such that closed point of B over $\mathbb{C}$ is a subgroup of closed point of A over $\mathbb{C}$(an abelian variety is a complete variety with a group structure)

Comment: This is called Poincaré complete reducibility theorem. It is in standard texts on abelian varieties, e.g. Mumford.